# Custom color hover on each posts in loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hover, addclass, removeclass

Can't find the logic for the following scenario:

There are six posts in a loop, each post have a color value set with custom fields.
When the mouse hovers over one of the post's excerpt it should change the excerpt's background to the color set with the custom field.

It's working but hovering over one posts reveals the hidden color for every posts and not just the one.

Is there any way I could store the post IDs in variables and then pass that variables to the JQuery addClass/removeClass function?

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<?php if( $2nd_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( $2nd_query->have_posts() ) : $2nd_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $display = get_field('color_setting');?>
            <div class="threesome">
            <div id="<?php echo $display ?>" class="indextitle_seethrou">
                <h2 class="indextitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div>  

                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('featured_thumb');
                } else {
                } ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
```

Then I have this Jquery:

```
$('.threesome').hover(function() {
$('.indextitle_seethrou').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
            }, function() {
$('.indextitle_seethrou').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
```

});

Obviously the above code won't work because of the threesome class. Is there any way to get the $display var in JQuery and then apply some css to it?

Comment: Some code would help. Please post some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:
from the loop (div that has an image and an invisible div with absolute position):

```
<div class="wrap">
<div id="<?php echo $display ?>" class="indextitle_seethrou">
</div>
<div class="pic">
    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('featured_thumb');
    } else {
    } ?>
</div>
</div><!--wrap ends -->
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".wrap").mouseover(function ()
{  
 $(this).children('div:first').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
});
 $(".wrap").mouseout(function ()
{ 
 $(this).children('div:first').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
});
});
```

There are many posts on a page each with its unique color value stored in $display variables.
I wanted to reveal the unique colors as an overlay with opacity over the images on hover.
In my first method I used a class as a selector but hovering over an image revealed all the overlays.
Instead of using a class as a selector I wrapped the whole thing in a div and targeted the first element in that div with JQuery. In my case the first element inside the wrap is the div with the unique background color I wanted to show on hover over the image.

Note that the **.wrap** , the **.pic** and the **.indextitle_seethrou** classes has absolute positioning in my CSS, the **.indextitle_seethrou** class also has a *display:none* CSS property.

Thank you.